# When to use "gather" versus "hunt"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a good and fast rule for when to the verb ‘gather’ versus ‘hunt’ for venturing out for food? I always thought that plants were gathered and animals were hunted. However  ‘mushroom hunting’ is common terminology. Is the exception that if a plant is hard to find then you are hunting for it?

Comment: I think you answered your own question, I don't think I could word it any better.

Comment: Saying that one *hunts* mushrooms strikes me as a somewhat jocose hyperbole, investing the activity with more machismo than it has. But I wonder if the distinction is more properly between food organisms that *actively* elude one and those that do not, rather than simply between animal and vegetable. I should think mussels, for instance, are rather gathered than hunted. (But then, I seem to recall reading that Chinese Buddhist monks, being vegetarian, classified the oyster as a vegetable.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan Collecting mussels was the other instance I was thinking of. I've heard of hunting for mussels and farming them so maybe it depends on if they are wild as well.

Comment: We've had the _gather_ vs _collect_ debate. 'Hunt' certainly does have obvious connotations from its more usual senses, but a denotation is 'To seek out; search for' [AHDEL]. The tally-ho/rifle connotation is certainly fainter with 'hunt for' than with 'hunt' / 'mushroom hunting'.

Comment: Before you can gather you have to find.  Mushrooms rarely grow in neat rows in a garden, so hunting is a prerequisite for gathering.

Comment: Strictly speaking, hunt should only be used for animals and prey, however because you often have to find the thing you are going to kill, the word drifted into "seek" and "look for."  It's kind of funny when applied to mushrooms, though.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - So  you've never had to hunt for your car keys in the morning?

Comment: @HotLicks I know this is going to sound weird but I have always said "look for." but I understand the other use.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - I agree -- you're weird. ;)

Comment: @HotLicks haha...that's what my students say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hunting** implies **seeking**, so if you don't know where it is, you have to hunt for it.     **Gathering** implies that what you need is where you expect it to be and is there for the taking.

Since most animals move around, and most plant foods are exactly where you expect them to be, you generally hunt animals and gather plants.  However, you certainly don't hunt cows or pigs, and if you know where the oysters are, you don't have to hunt them; you can just gather them.

As for mushrooms, I'll buy mine in the supermarket, thank you.

Comment: We're not hunter-gathers anymore and we buy most of our food items in the market. But the OP needs the answer, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

*Hunt* is for something that you have to run after, while *gather* is for something that is just there for you to pick up.